# Is there a way to retrieve the Computer Name of a Xenapp client?

Tags: c#, thin-client, xenapp

What options exist for identifying the client name of a particular client from within the process running on Citrix Presentation 4.0, or Xenapp 5, and are there any important differences in retrieving this information in either scenario?

Currently my software is a client that connects to a service on a server, and the primary means of identification are computer name and IP Address.  When installed on a Citrix Presentation server, all running instances currently show the same Computer Name and IP Address, which are those of the server.

My application is written in VB 6.0, however I am looking to implement the new feature in C# .NET.

Any help or clarification on the question itself would be appreciated, as I am not experienced with developing for Citrix thin clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this information is stored in the environment variable called CLIENTNAME, and it is only in the Process Environment.  I used the following code:

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CLIENTNAME", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```